# Check User-Agent with jsf

Tags: jsf, user-agent

I want to check the user agent of my client. (If it's possible the browser type/version)

But I don't know how do that...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is OK, I have find.
I use :

```
final HttpServletRequest request =(HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
final String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
System.out.println(userAgent);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It would be nice for ThiefMaster if you accepted his answer though. :)

Answer (score 7):

It is sent in the `User-Agent` http header.

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, but what is `context` ? How I can initialize it ?

Answer (score 5):

In a JSF2 page, you can print the user agent directly via the request object:

```
<h:outputText value="#{request.getHeader('user-agent')}" />
```

But don't forget to use the **h-namespace** ;-)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

You can then respond via functions to different browsers.

**Example:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p>
            User-Agent: <h:outputText value="#{request.getHeader('user-agent')}" />
        </p>       
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(request.getHeader('User-Agent'), 'Firefox')}">
            <p>
                Hello Firefox!
            </p>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: `#{header['user-agent']}` is simpler.