# How to generate different HTML based on the device that access the page?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am using Java EE 6 with all the reference implementations and I wonder how you can generate different responses based on the device accessing the page? At the moment when I develop a JSF page I target browsers running on PC. However I want to generate another HTML structure (that is, using another JSF page) when the user browses the page with a smart phone.

Now you wonder, "Why doesn't you use CSS media queries?". Yes, I could but that will only give limited control over the layout. Could someone give me some hints to where and what to start reading about to do this?

I don't want to use Spring, I know they have something like this.

Comment: Since you want to solve this problem server-side, it sounds like you just want to find out which user-agent(read 'browser') is accessing your site, in which case you may use this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688069/check-user-agent-with-jsf). This approach however has some [caveats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I don't want to use Spring, I know they have something like this.*

Just reinvent it then (*cough*).

[Let's look how they did it](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring%20mobile%20device%20detection). According to the [Spring Mobile documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-mobile/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/), cited below,

> #### LiteDeviceResolver
>
> The default `DeviceResolver` implementation is based on the "lite" [detection algorithm](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-mobile-pack/trunk/plugins/wpmp_switcher/lite_detection.php) implemented as part of the [Wordpress Mobile Pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack). This resolver only detects the presence of a mobile device and does not detect specific capabilities. No special configuration is required to enable this resolver, simply configure a default DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor and it will be enabled for you.

it seems that they have ported [this piece of PHP code](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-mobile-pack/trunk/plugins/wpmp_switcher/lite_detection.php) to [this piece of Java code](http://git.springsource.org/spring-mobile/spring-mobile/blobs/a4054d3c6c460edc1019a9ee5b35251ba446f448/spring-mobile-device/src/main/java/org/springframework/mobile/device/lite/LiteDeviceResolver.java).  You could just do the same (be aware of license rules!). The most sensible place for this would be a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which would then send a redirect depending on the outcome of the detection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to look to the HTTP_USER_AGENT.

No experience with Java, but look to System.getEnv("HTTP_USER_AGENT").

It should return a string name for the user agent. You should find in the web lists of common user agents, so you can easily classify them as mobile or not mobile.

Comment: how to use it? at least give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect HTTP header

user-agent

you can retrieve this using Servlet API: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: And where do I go from there? How do I serve the JSF page adapted for mobiles etc?

Comment: you can use user-agent and then based on the value (which you need to test by hitting the server with different clients), you generate either one page or another - in JSF, you would use different navigations. Actually, come to think, JSF is far removed from Servlet API, but there is still a way to get to it, need to explore JSF docs to see how to read HTTP headers. The navigation is in the faces-config.xml, I hope this helps