# Trying to write different code based on user-agent

Tags: dictionary, user-agent

I am coding a site and trying to make the mobile optimised part of the site work with a 'Find Us' button. I don't need to have anything fancy, and I now know what href to use to invoke using the 'Maps' app on Iphone, Android, Blackberry and windows phone. (thanks to: [John Allan's post](http://habaneroconsulting.com/blog/posts/Opening_native_map_apps_from_the_mobile_browser.aspx#.UaW92pxnC6g))

So, what I want to do now is to find either Java or another form that will let me put in the required links based upon the user-agent.

For example: I know for the Iphone I need to enter:

```
 <a href="http://maps.google.com/?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr= 894%20Granville%20Street%20Vancouver%20BC%20V6Z%201K3">Find Us</a>
```

And for Andriod:

```
<a href="geo:894%20Granville%20Street%20Vancouver%20BC%20V6Z%201K3">Find Us</a>
```

However, I do not know how to make the code enter the right link for the right user-agent. I would like to do it inline if possible or with as little script as possible.

I have tried JSF from the post found here [Check-User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688069/check-user-agent-with-jsf), but that code didn't work on my site. Currently I am just writing in HTML5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could do it with a JavaScript function `writeGeoLink('Vancouver', ...)`. Please mention what you are using with respect to templating: Java Server Faces, plain JSP, or whatever. In JSF you could make an expression language function.

Comment: I updated my question. I currently don't use JSF - I did try but couldn't get it to work. Just coding in plain HTML5

Comment: Then it's `<%= geoLink(request, "Vancouver", ...) %>`. I can understand that about JSF, but in a simple IDE like NetBeans, and the latest JSF one no longer can get lost (after a tutorial or 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom [taglib](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html).

You can make your own custom tags `<my:geoLink city="Vancouver" ...>...</my:geoLink>`, defined in a JSP code containing tag file, with `<c:if test="request.userAgent = '...'>` or so.